# Can I create a linear git history using 3 permanent branches?

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase

I am working with a 4 dev team and I want to have a linear git history using the **rebase and merge** gitHub function. We will be using 3 main branches: **development**, **staging** and **main**.

My idea is that developers would branch feature branches off development, rebase them into development, then after each sprint we would rebase staging

My problem is that I cannot get the git history to be linear, I get duplicated commits when using **rebase and merge** and I am not getting why it is not working as I expect it to.

I created a repo to practice, I created the development branch and added a few feature branches, created pull requests and used **rebase and merge** to get the code into development, that works great. Here is an image example using git graph.
[image: development branch with a few feaure branches rebased and merged into it]
Now my intention is to get what is on development into **staging**, so I created a PR in gitHub:
[image: gitHub PR from development to staging]
After using **rebase and merge** I get this:[image]

I expected the staging branch to be on the same commit as development, I'd also have the same issue with main when trying to put the code from staging into main. Is there a way I can achieve a linear git history with the **rebase and merge** gitHub function?

Answer (score 2):

Rebase and merge is a solution that works well for temporary branches, that you're about to delete, but not for permanent ones. If you use permanent branches, you will need actual merges between them, there's no way to avoid that.

When you run rebase and merge, you are asking Git to create new commits with the same contents, so by definition they are not going to be the same commits.

You can work with a nearly linear history by rebasing your feature branches, though, and then get used to seeing merges between the permanent branches. There won't be many such merges if you're only doing them once per sprint, so the history should still be easy to read.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, it makes sense that I need merge commits for permanent branches but it does create a situation where my staging branch is n commits behind main every time I make n merges, because of the merge commits. Is this expected? Given that those merge commits hold no real changes. 

Also, the situation gets more complex when a hotfix occurs, is there a recommended way to handle this?

Comment: After meeting to main, you can merge back to staging to resolve that. I'm not sure all workflows do it this way, but I always merge back from release to main, from main to staging, so that the next feature branches and hotfix breaches can start from a point that's not behind main.